# Haskell: Couldn't match type?

Tags: haskell

One last question regarding type matching (for the time being, at least, lol).

In the following **takeS** formula right at the bottom of my code, I want to output a specific number of elements in a Snoc list defined as follows:

```
data ListS a = NilS 
              |Snoc (ListS a) a deriving Show

initS :: ListS a -> ListS a
initS NilS          = error "Empty List"
initS (Snoc a b)    = a

lastS :: ListS a -> a
lastS NilS          = error "Empty List"
lastS (Snoc _ b)    = b

headS :: ListS a -> a
headS NilS          = error "Empty List"
headS (Snoc NilS b) = b
headS (Snoc a b)    = headS a

tailS :: ListS a -> ListS a
tailS NilS          = error "Empty List"
tailS (Snoc NilS a) = NilS
tailS (Snoc a b)    = (Snoc (tailS a) b)    

reverseS :: ListS a -> ListS a
reverseS NilS = NilS
reverseS l = (Snoc (reverseS(tailS(l))) (headS l))

takeS :: Int -> ListS a -> ListS a
takeS 0 _    = NilS
takeS _ NilS = error "Empty List"
takeS n l    = if n >= len(l) then 
               takeAux len(l) reverseS(l) else takeAux n reverseS(l) where
                   takeAux 0 l = l
                   takeAux n l = (Snoc (takeAux (n-1) initS(l)) (lastS l))
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Google Drive\Ejercicio01.hs:31:20: error:
    * Couldn't match type `ListS a4' with `ListS a3 -> ListS a3'
      Expected type: t -> (ListS a3 -> ListS a3) -> ListS a4 -> ListS a4
        Actual type: t -> ListS a4 -> ListS a4
    * In an equation for `takeS':
          takeS n l
            = if n >= len (l) then
                  takeAux len (l) reverseS (l)
              else
                  takeAux n reverseS (l)
            where
                takeAux 0 l = l
                takeAux n l = (Snoc (takeAux (n - 1) initS (l)) (lastS l))
    * Relevant bindings include
        takeAux :: t -> (ListS a3 -> ListS a3) -> ListS a4 -> ListS a4
          (bound at C:\Users\Google Drive\Ejercicio01.hs:31:20)
   |
97 |                    takeAux 0 l = l
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

As I see  it, I'm trying to output the same type of list, but Haskell says I am creating a different type when calling the auxiliary function. Is that correct? It can get a bit confusing when dealing with these kind of errors at the beginning, so, besides helping me out by pointing at what the problem is, I would like to know if there's a repository or guide to understand better the intricacies of Haskell.

Thank you!

Comment: An important observation in your error message: `len(l)` doesn't parse to a function call like in most other languages, but as two separate expressions `len` and `(l)`.  Writing `(len l)` (and, correspondingly, `(reverseS l)`) might be more correct and confuse the compiler less.

Comment: `takeAux len(l) reverseS(l)` is calling `takeAux` with _four_ arguments (the parentheses are redundant).

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that! Thank you for the observation. You are correct, I am calling length when, in fact, in my code I also implemented a lenS function which works with Lists of the type Snoc. 

I really appreciate all of your corrections, it's helping me a big deal to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not writing curried applications right. Should be something like

```
takeS n l = if n >= (len l) then 
           takeAux (len l) (reverseS l) else takeAux n (reverseS l) where
               takeAux 0 l = l
               takeAux n l = (Snoc (takeAux (n-1) (initS l)) (lastS l))
```

Parentheses are used for grouping in Haskell, never as an operator (tuple construction put aside.)

As a side note, there are few inconsistencies in your code:

1. Are there any name clashes with standard Prelude in your code? `len` is a standard function that measures the length of lists.
2. `reverse` is quadratic. Why do you need `headS` and `tailS` here, when you've got init and last in no time (i.e. in O(1))?
3. There's inconsistency in `takeS` contract: `takeS 2 NilS` is an error yet `takeS 3 (Snoc NilS 42)` returns a tsil. You don't really need length in the last match.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually just realized I was using the len functions rather than the one I declared (lenS, for Snoc lists). I also appreciate the observation regarding complexity. I'll get onto that as well.

Comment: My code runs now. I will curry the right way from now on. Thank you for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

The type checker has messed up the type of `takeAux` in a very interesting way.  The error message is therefore confusing.  Write a type signature above takeAux in the where clause `takeAux :: Int -> ListS a -> ListS a` and haskell will give you a much better error message centered at a different line.

As a general rule when you get a type checking error on an auxilriy function without a type signature and the cause is not blindly obvious, adding a type signature will give you a much clearer error message.  It also helps to document your code.

Comment: Thank you John, I will keep that in mind from now on. Much appreciated.